# Sql - alternative to WITH ... AS

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there an **efficient** alternative SQL to this example? I do not want to use WITH ... AS, that is the main criteria

```
WITH TEMP_TABLE AS (
     SELECT status, COUNT(1) as total FROM XYZ GROUP BY status
    )
SELECT 
         NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'A'),0) AS A_COUNT ,
         NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'B'),0) AS B_COUNT ,
         NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'C'),0) AS C_COUNT ,
         NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'D'),0) AS D_COUNT , 
         NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'E'),0) AS E_COUNT ,
         NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'F'),0) AS F_COUNT  
FROM DUAL;
```

I read similar questions but they use other ddl stuff, I just want a basic SQL statement.

Comment: So you want to know how to get rid of the [CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775056/creating-a-cte-in-oracle) from your statement?  CTE's are hugely powerful and efficient... why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: Yes I know and like it but reason is Mule platform does not support it, at least not  in a practical way. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36877716/2815227

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I didn't understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A_COUNT ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B_COUNT ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C_COUNT ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D_COUNT ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS E_COUNT ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F_COUNT 
FROM XYZ ;
```

I should point out that putting the values on separate rows is even easier:

```
select status, count(*)
from xyz
group by status;
```

Comment: an answer in seconds :) trying right now! In my case it is more practical them to be in the same row, as I will trnaslate the result to a json object

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple PIVOT query

```
select *
from (select status from XYZ )
pivot (
   count(*) for status in (
      'A' as a_count, 'B' as b_count, 
      'C' as c_count, 'D' as d_count, 
      'E' as e_count, 'F' as f_count 
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Already given answers are perfect, you should use them. However in order to provide you a general solution (perhaps you have to transform other queries) it would be this one:

```
SELECT 
     NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'A'),0) AS A_COUNT ,
     NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'B'),0) AS B_COUNT ,
     NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'C'),0) AS C_COUNT ,
     NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'D'),0) AS D_COUNT , 
     NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'E'),0) AS E_COUNT ,
     NVL((SELECT TOTAL  FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'F'),0) AS F_COUNT  
FROM 
    (SELECT status, COUNT(1) as total FROM XYZ GROUP BY status) TEMP_TABLE;
```